# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I can't figure out the problem with the code as I have even matched it with the source code provided by the git user and it is same, but still showing error
**So below is the error**:-
[image: error]

**Below is the code for shortenAddress component:-**

```
 export const shortenAddress = (address) => `${address.slice(0, 5)}...${address.slice(address.length - 4)}`;
```

**Below is the code of the Welcome component**

```
        <p className="text-white font-light te-xt-sm">{shortenAddress(currentAccount) }</p>
```

Please,can someone tell the answer to this question of mine...

Comment: `currentAccount === undefined`? You might want to check if its truthy before calling the function - `currentAccount && shortenAddress(currentAccount)`

Comment: your `currentAccount` must be `undefined`, check

Comment: you can also use optional chaining to avoid getting the error like `address?.slice(0, 5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because, when you wont get `address` then address is undefined and not an array.

What you can do is, check address exists like

```
export const shortenAddress = (address) => {
  if(address.length) {
    return `${address.slice(0, 5)}...${address.slice(address.length - 4)}`
  }
  return address
}
```

OR you can also optional chaining `?` operator:

```
export const shortenAddress = (address) => `${address?.slice(0, 5)}...${address?.slice(address.length - 4)}`;
```

Let me know, if you feel any issue.